# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server, procedure, tsql, cursor

[image]

Eu tenho uma *procedure* que envia e-mail com os dados da tabela, inclusive o e-mail que será encaminhado,mas ela esta enviando para apenas o 1 registro, o segundo ela passa reto, e ela está em Loop Infinito, enviando vários Emails para apenas o 1o registro

PROCEDURE:

```
USE [Testes]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspEnviarEmail]    Script Date: 28/10/2015 11:05:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEnviarEmail]

AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE  @_profileName VARCHAR(10)
   DECLARE  @_recipients VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @_body VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @_subject VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Contador AS INT = 0

DECLARE CursorEmails CURSOR FOR

SELECT 
    profileName,
    recipients,
    body,
    subjectEmail
    FROM
    Emails
OPEN CursorEmails

FETCH NEXT FROM CursorEmails INTO @_profileName,@_recipients,@_body,@_subject

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
SET @Contador = @Contador +1

SET @_profileName=
(
    SELECT profileName FROM Emails 
)

SET @_recipients=
(
    STUFF((SELECT';'+RTRIM(LTRIM(recipients))  FROM Emails FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
)

SET @_body=
(
    SELECT body FROM Emails 
)
SET @_subject=
(
    SELECT subjectEmail FROM Emails 
)


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

@profile_name = @_profileName,
@recipients = @_recipients,
@body = @_body,
@subject = @_subject
END
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorEmails INTO @_profileName,@_recipients,@_body,@_subject
END
```

Comment: Por favor, confira o resultado antes de publicar, existe uma formatação específica para código: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: É SQL Server o banco?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, o erro de retorno é referente a uma consulta que retornar mais de um valor quando o esperado é apenas 1.

veja o trecho abaixo :

```
SET @_body=
(
    SELECT body FROM Emails 
)
```

use o id da tabela Emails  com *cláusula where* para fazer a busca dos dados corretos.  tipo

```
SELECT body FROM Emails where id = 1
```

Altere os trechos abaixo com o *id* ta tabela...

```
BEGIN
 declare  @IdEmail int
 DECLARE  @_profileName VARCHAR(10)

 DECLARE CursorEmails CURSOR FOR
 SELECT 
    IdEmail,
    profileName,
    recipients,
    body,
    subjectEmail
    FROM
    Emails


 FETCH NEXT FROM CursorEmails INTO @IdEmail, @_profileName,@_recipients,@_body,@_subject

 FETCH NEXT FROM CursorEmails INTO @IdEmail, @_profileName,@_recipients,@_body,@_subject
```